# Coldfusion : how to update multiple record with one ID

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

This is actually continue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508291/coldfusion-mssql-how-to-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-unique-id-in-one-submi).

Say a teacher wanted to update the student's skill. The process goes like this:

1. Select student's name.
2. View Student's profile.
3. Click UPDATE link. The UPDATE page shows a list of skills with checkboxes.
4. The teacher can check or uncheck the student's skills. Then clicks submit.

E.g:

```
+------+------------------------+
Draw   |   <checkbox checked > 
+------+------------------------+
Read   |   <checkbox> 
+------+------------------------+
Dance  |   <checkbox checked >
+------+------------------------+
```

So here's the problem;

1. How can I update multiple submission with one ID? (compare the submission value with the one in database)
2. How can I add (INSERT INTO) when the skillid does not exist in table studentskill?

**table skill**

```
+---------+------------+
| skillid | skillname  |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | draw       |
+---------+------------+
| 2       | read       |
+---------+------------+
| 3       | dance      |
+---------+------------+
```

**table studentskill**

```
+----------+----------|
|studentid | skillid  |
+----------+----------+
| 001      | 1        |
| 001      | 2        |
| 002      | 1        |
| 002      | 2        |
| 002      | 3        |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Don't you also have to delete a skill if it was unchecked?

Comment: @orandov :  there is a skill_flag column in studentskill table. if the teacher wants to unchecked the check box, it will update to 0. (by default, the skill_flag value will be 1 when teacher submit the student's skill)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Leigh's answer. I would just add (and this addition was too long for a comment) the following:

1) Avoid deleting all records and then re-adding them. Someday you may decide you want extra data in that table and you will lose it whenever this code runs if you delete all of the skills. It is easy enough to add the WHERE clause correctly, so you may as well do it.

2) I would recommend using a "WHERE NOT EXISTS" rather than an OUTER JOIN to ensure that the records don't already exist in the student skills table. The OUTER JOIN might perform a little better, but the WHERE NOT EXISTS should perform good enough in this situation and will be much clearer.

After all, you said "when the skillid does not exist in table studentskill" and "WHERE NOT EXISTS" reads very much like that.

```
 <cftransaction>
   <cfquery ...>
      DELETE
      FROM StudentSkill
       WHERE  studentID = <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
       <cfif listLen(form.skillId)>
         AND  skillId NOT IN (<cfqueryparam value="#form.skillId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true">)
       </cfif>
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery ...>
       INSERT INTO StudentSkill ( studentId, skillId )
       SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
                , skillId
       FROM   Skill
       WHERE  skillId IN (<cfqueryparam value="#form.skillId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true">)
       AND    NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM     StudentSkill
                    WHERE   studentID = <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
                        AND skillID = Skill.skillID
                )
    </cfquery>
  </cftransaction>
```

As noted earlier, wrapping the whole thing in cftransaction will ensure that either the entite set of changes happen or none at all.

Comment: Yep, `not exists` is another option and I would agree it is more intuitive. In may even be a little less expensive than an `outer` join. But you would have to check the actual query plan.

Comment: @vamps - Also, I see from later comments the `studentSkill` table may contain additional data beyond student and skill id's. If that is the case, Steve is right. You definitely want to go with the second option.

Comment: Yes @leigh, i did realize that and i was going to update the answer until i read steve bryant answer which is more correct. thanks, both of you.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

It turns out the `StudentSkill` contains additional columns (beyond StudentID and SkillID). [Steve Bryant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069602/104223) is a better choice for that scenario.

---

One common approach is to `DELETE` all existing skills for the selected student first. Then `INSERT` the new skills. Pros: It is a little more straightforward than the second approach Cons: Does a delete every time, even if nothing is changed.

```
   <!--- change cfsqltypes if needed --->
   <cfquery ...>
      DELETE FROM StudentSkill
      WHERE  studentID = <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
   </cfquery>

   <cfquery ...>
        INSERT INTO studenSkill ( studenId, skillId )
        SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
               , skillId
        FROM   skill
        WHERE  skillId IN 
               (
               <cfqueryparam value="#form.skillId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true">
               )
   </cfquery>
```

Another approach is to `DELETE` only skills that were unchecked/removed. Then use an  `OUTER JOIN` to `INSERT` skills that were newly added. Anything else is considered unchanged.

```
   <cfquery ...>
      DELETE FROM StudentSkill
      WHERE  studentID = <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
      <cfif listLen(form.skillId)>
        AND  skillId NOT IN 
             (
               <cfqueryparam value="#form.skillId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true">
             )
      </cfif>
   </cfquery>

   <cfquery ...>
      INSERT INTO StudentSkill ( studenId, skillId )
      SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
               , s.skillId
      FROM   Skill s LEFT JOIN StudentSkill stu 
                 ON   s.skillID = stu.skillID
                 AND  stu.studentID = <cfqueryparam value="#form.studentId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
      WHERE  s.skillId IN 
               (
               <cfqueryparam value="#form.skillId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true">
               )
      AND    stu.skillID IS NULL
   </cfquery>
```

Note: Be sure to wrap both queries in a `cftransaction` so they are treated as a single unit.

Comment: :thanks for the heads up. this is the first time i heard about cftransaction.

Comment: Anytime you have "related queries" that modify the database, you want to use a transaction. It ensures *all* of the queries succeed or they all fail. So you never leave things in an inconsistent state. This is an old article, but the first section provides a good description of why transactions are needed using the [classic bank transfer example](http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072705-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 supports Table Valued Parameters but I don't know if that is support in ColdFusion.

See this answer: [Passing a Table Valued parameter to a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683869/passing-a-table-valued-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure).

In that answer there is a link of how to pass a list as XML to a stored procedure. In the stored procedure you would load the XML list to a temp table and insert and delete records by joining on the temp table.

Comment: The ColdFusion part to this scenario would be to create the xml string that gets sent to the stored procedure.  CF has sufficient functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

@leigh provided a good answer but another approach may be to display your "selected" options as links rather than check boxes.  The link would prompt you to confirm the removal of the option and refresh the page.

Then your check box handling would only be for the addition of new records (which it sounds like your already doing).  This would help prevent people from accidentally checking the wrong box and having the skill deleted.