# Pass list to SQL custom type

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I want to pass a list of school years from Coldfusion 10 to a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008 R2.  I created a custom type in MSSQL:

```
CREATE TYPE YearListType AS Table (years VARCHAR(10))
```

And then my stored procedure declares this in my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [getCounts]
    @years YearListType readonly
    ....
    SELECT .......
    WHERE school_year IN (SELECT * FROM @years)
```

Now  in my Coldfusion, I call the stored procedure this way:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="[getCounts]" datasource="...">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#yrlist#">
     ....
 </cfstoredproc>
```

The variable yrlist is a comma delimited list.  Sample value looks like:

```
"2001-2002,2002-2003,2003-2004"
```

When I execute, I get a CF error:

```
Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with YearListType
```

I understand the error, but I don't know how else to pass the list.  I tried adding list="yes" to the cfprocparam, but I get an error saying the list parameter isn't compatible with cfprocparam.  As far as I know, there is no cf_sql_list type, is there?

How should I pass a list of values to my stored procedure?  Should I even use a custom SQL data type at all?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617706/passing-an-in-list-via-stored-procedure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values/43767#43767), but I can't figure out the Coldfusion side of it.

Comment: You might need to just pass the proc (and have the proc expect ~) a `varchar`, then convert the `varchar` to a `YearListType` within the proc itself.

Comment: Is this really the cleanest way to do this? Doesn't anyone else pass CF lists to stored procedures?

Comment: Has ColdFusion been updated since TVPs were introduced (SQL Server 2008)? Do they have any documentation on table-valued parameters? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683869/passing-a-table-valued-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure and http://isitaboutmycube.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/coldfusion-table-value-parameters-using-net/ (found from [a pretty basic Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=pass+TVP+from+coldfusion)).

Comment: It's not that you can't pass a list, it's that you can't pass a `YearListType`, which I guess is some custom type you've defined.

Comment: @AdamCameron How would you pass a list that I can use in a WHERE ... IN()  clause in my stored procedure?  Everything I've tried, SQL treats the list as a long varchar and I get no results.

Comment: Dude, I'm the wrong person to ask. My T-SQL is very 101 level. Lemme put some feelers out for some help though.

Comment: (Edit) On second thought, I do not think casting is an option since it appears to be some sort of `table` type. However, as mentioned you can always set the parameter type to `varchar`. Then use one of the many "split" techniques, such [using xml](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/), to convert the csv list into rows. The result can be used like a table, similar to your current approach. *Should I even use a custom SQL data type at all?* Not sure what the benefit is here, over using the "split" approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before. You first need to create a function to split the list apart then call that in your SQL like this.  FTR: I didn't create this, I found it via Google several years ago. If I had the original source links I would have referenced those hre. I'm sure Google still has them. Just search for "T-SQL fnSplit".

```
SELECT blah FROM foo WHERE bar IN (fnSplit(@valueList, ','))
```

This is the function you need to create.

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnSplit]    Script Date: 09/06/2011 19:08:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
        @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
        , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
        ) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

    BEGIN
            DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
            WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
            BEGIN
            SELECT
            @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
            @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

            IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
            INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
            END

            IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
            INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
            RETURN
        END
GO
```

Comment: Yeah, I remember using something similar with earlier versions of SQL Server. There are [newer versions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17185369/104223) that use some neat XML tricks to achieve the same result.

Comment: This is basically what we do on SQL Server 2008

Comment: Not the answer I WANT, but I think it might be the best available.  Thanks

Comment: Much better split alternatives here http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: And when you aren't handcuffed by not being able to use TVPs, http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion does not have a "list" attribute for `<cfprocparam>`,  but it does for `<cfqueryparam>`. So you could try calling your stored procedure using a sql statement, like you would from within SQL Server Management Studio, and use `<cfqueryparam>` to wrap your parameters.

This still won't address the issue that ColdFusion does not (and cannot) understand SQL Server custom datatypes.  If you are generating the year list programmatically rather than from user input (or you are sanitizing the user input before using it), you can omit the `cfsqltype` attribute from `<cfqueryparam>`.